# Cannot resolve symbol 'item'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menuitem

I'm trying to make my menu items go to different activities, so I tried to override the onOptionsItemSelcted on every activity, but I'm getting this error.

also getting "Constant expression required" on every case "R.id.ItemX".

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu){

        switch (item.getItemId()){ // ERROR IS HERE ON THE WORD 'item', Cannot resolve symbol 'item'.

            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

            case R.id.Item1: // Constant expression required

                goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                break;

            case R.id.Item2: // Constant expression required

                goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VidPage.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                break;

            case R.id.Item3: // Constant expression required

                goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DatePage.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                break;


        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you declare ``item`` anywhere? It isn't declared in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
menu.getItemId()
```

Instead of this

```
item.getItemId()
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu){

        switch (menu.getItemId()){ // ERROR IS HERE ON THE WORD 'item', THE REST WORKS FINE.

            Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

            case R.id.Item1:

                goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                break;

            case R.id.Item2:

                goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VidPage.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                break;

            case R.id.Item3:

                goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DatePage.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);
                break;


        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: was going to suggest this as well. `item` is not within scope of the method as defined in the question... `menu` of type `MenuItem` is however

Answer (score 0):

use this

menu.getItemId()

this will return you the item id,